# Location of the rascal father time

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> I'm sometimes a cheetah in the free
>  Sometimes a sloth in a tree
>  I'm time itself
>   ofcourse
>  The fourth hour
>  I'm in a
>   bit of rebellion, I changed dimension
>  Measure me all you'd
>   like
>  I'd only taunt your instruments
>  Unless you get it right
>   of course
>  A dipleidoscope, pff fancy, but no
>  Not useful
>   any longer
>  A king might be able to help you
>  Hahah
>  Haha
>  I
>   flew over here. Now you surely got my number!
>  Where am I now?
>  I entered the savannah at noon
>  If that helps

Answer is ~one word

Edit: Made it a little bit easier

Hint 1:

> Line numbers

Hint 2:

> The savannah line un-far-fetch'ified => 'I was a cheetah at noon' (this hint is only useful once you've figured out what time changed about his nature).

<strike>Hint 3:</strike> (not useful in simplified version)

> <strike>The fourth line relates directly to Hint 1. To make the fourth line correct: Change 'dimension' for 'hour'</strike>

Hint 4:

> He will taunt you if you try to measure time with a watch. A instrument which may work is a ruler or even easier a text editor which shows line numbers

Hint 5:

> There are some lines without a lot of significance such as the *sloth* line, the *unless you get it right* line or the last line.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm sorry for making such an obscure hard to solve puzzle! Hopefully i learned something from it! Here is the answer:

The answer is:

> 15:00

**Explanation:**

I'm sometimes a cheetah in the free
Sometimes a sloth in a tree
I'm time itself of course

> These lines 'establishes' that 'I' is Time. Time has written the riddle

The fourth hour

> Clue that fourth line is fourth hour

I'm in a bit of rebellion, I changed dimension

> This is where the riddle fails the most. The core concept i wanted to build the riddle about was that time progressed through the space dimension rather than the time dimension. This is a long leap and this is the only thing that indicates that. **Every line is 1 hour**

Measure me all you'd like
I'd only taunt your instruments

> Since Time has changed it so that time progresses downwards from the beginning of this text. you can no longer measure time with e.g watches.

Unless you get it right of course

> Filler with no meaning. Thing i learned: do not include things which do not help towards the answer if you are a beginner riddle maker

A dipleidoscope, pff fancy, but no
Not useful any longer

> Almost filler as well, an tiny inkling of help that you cannot use the sun to measure time

A king might be able to help you

> King = ruler. So you can measure distance, very clever, and impossible clue to get as the setup of the riddle is so barebones/nonexistant

Hahah
Haha
I flew over here. Now you surely got my number!

> Hinting that time had fun taunting you, so time progressed quickly. (aka lines where short and went fast). Hints that line numbers are important

Where am I now?

> That is the actual question of the riddle. line 15 is 15th hour, which is the answer. And since Time has changed the dimensons of reality itself, then 15:00 is an actual physical location, justifying the 'where'.

I entered the savannah at noon

> Time became fast when father time laughed a.k.a. line 12 (noon)

If that helps

> Filler which i remember putting there for aesthetic purposes.

All in all I had fun when I made it, but quickly realized my mistakes. Feel free to comment angrily. It is probably a cool riddle somewhere in there around the concept of changing time's dimension, but this execution was no good.

Comment: If nothing else you can consider it a learning experience. I can't speak for everyone around here but people will generally consider every part of a riddle to be important to solving it, so putting in filler lines or things that don't connect will only result in a larger number of incorrect guesses. It's also not often that things are spelled out blatantly, so "I'm time itself of course" probably wouldn't have been interpreted literally by many people. XD

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I am:

> Light

I'm sometimes a cheetah in the free

> Light is sometimes fast

Sometimes a sloth in a tree

> Light is sometimes slow (the speed of light changes based on medium)

I'm time itself of course

> The speed of light and time are directly linked (theory of relativity)

The fourth hour

> Not sure about this line

I'm in a bit of rebellion, I changed dimension

> Until recently, light was thought to move through an ethereal dimension (due to its wavelike properties)

Measure me all you'd like
I'd only taunt your instruments

> The speed of light is strange, and, while easy to measure, is relative to the person measuring

Unless you get it right of course
A dipleidoscope, pff fancy, but no
Not useful any longer

> Measuring light doesn't require any fancy instruments

A king might be able to help you

> "El Rey" is Spanish for king. A ray of light?

Hahah
Haha
I flew over here. Now you surely got my number!

> Perhaps referring to the speed of light

Where am I now?
I entered the savannah at noon
If that helps

> The one thing obviously in the desert at noon, is sunlight!

Comment: Nice angle, I've realised how 'impossible/hard' this riddle is though! Way to much noise and to few actually helpful clues! Will post an explanation when i get home I think!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are:

> God

I'm sometimes a cheetah in the free, sometimes a sloth in a tree

> Many ancient/existing religions consider some animals to be a reincarnation or avatar of God

I'm time itself ofcourse

> Some believe time was a creation of God

I'm in a bit of rebellion, I changed dimension

> Wars have been fought and there are many issues over different religions/existence of God. As for the "dimension" part, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EKi6ETuOclA) shows that God might exist in other dimensions

Measure me all you'd like, I'd only taunt your instruments

> No one has been able to prove or disprove God's existence. Furthermore, [this link](http://www.rrnc.org/2014/02/ephesians-320-immeasurable-4-things-measured/) shows that you cannot measure His power, grace, love, and rewards.

Unless you get it right of course

> Religions faith?

A dipleidoscope, pff fancy, but no
Not useful any longer

> Cannot measure God

A king might be able to help you

> In Ancient Egypt and other civilizations they believed the king (pharaoh) had spiritual connections with God

Hahah, Haha

> Umm?

I flew over here. Now you surely got my number!

> Some mystical beings (gods) have been able to fly. Not sure about my number, maybe referring to God's number (20) or the devil's number (666).

Where am I now?

> Going back to God's existence

I entered the savannah at noon, if that helps

> It doesn't, really...

Also:

> Maybe it's a specific God or other supernatural being, like Cronos